# Existence of isomorphism in field extension

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

**Problem** If $a$ and $b$ be any two conjugates over the field $F$, then there always exist an isomorphism $\psi: F(a)\to F(b)$ such that $\psi(a)=b$ and $\psi(k)=k$ for all $k\in F$.

---

We are given that $a$ and $b$ are conjugates over $F$ therefore they satisfy the same minimal polynomial say $p(x)$ over $F$. Then there exist an isomorphism

$\phi:F(a)\to F[x]/ \langle p(x)\rangle$  given by $\phi(k)=k+\langle p(x)\rangle$ and $ \phi(a)=x+\langle p(x)\rangle$

similarly, we can define a map $\phi^*$
$\phi^*:F(b)\to F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$  given by $\phi^*(k)=k+\langle p(x)\rangle$ and $ \phi^*(b)=x+\langle p(x)\rangle$.

$\phi^*$ is isomorphism.

Then there exist a composition map $\sigma:F(a)\xrightarrow{\psi} F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle\xrightarrow{{\phi^*}^{-1}} F(b)$.

It's done.

Am I right?
Any hint or help will be appreciable. Thanks!

Comment: Try composing the isomorphisms.

Comment: @SBRJCT Please see my recent edits. Am I proceeding right?

Comment: Yep, that’s it!